# How robust are TCP/IP checksums

Tags: networking, tcp

How robust are TCP/IP checksums compared with CRC32 or something like that. They're only a 1B bit complement or something more sophisticated (but slower)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Checksum_computation

> The TCP checksum is a weak check by modern standards. Data Link Layers with high bit error rates may require additional link error correction/detection capabilities. The weak checksum is partially compensated for by the common use of a CRC or better integrity check at layer 2, below both TCP and IP, such as is used in PPP or the Ethernet frame.